# how to load a php function with jquery load function?

Tags: php, jquery, function, load

i have a script that i use to load some content:

```
<script>
$(".link_image").click(ajax_request);
function ajax_request() {
    $('#placeholder').load("../test.php?id=1234556");
}
</script>
```

this will load test.php into my div. but what if i want to load a function that is inside `test.php`:

```
get_title();
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, do you want to load a PHP function from Javascript or a Javascript function generated by test.php?

Comment: Ehm, I'm not sure what you mean; why don't you just make the request to test.php return the result of an invokation of the get_title() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call php functions from javascript as the PHP processing happens before the javascript is outputted to the page.  (Basically the PHP script is no longer running when the client sees the page)

What you can do is get the output of that function using AJAX, and then use javascript to put the result wherever you want.  Ask if you have any further questions.

EDIT: To be more specific, you can create a php file that essentially does

```
echo get_title();
```

and load that to get the output of get_title().

Answer (score 3):

You can also call the URL appending a querystring indicating the function to call:

```
$('#placeholder').load("../test.php?id=1234556&func=get_title");
```

In your PHP:

```
if ($_GET["func"] == "get_title") {
    get_title();
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side, and JavaScript is client-side. You can't.

You can, however, call a PHP script via AJAX which prints the result of your `the_title()` function, but you can't "call" `the_title()` function as if you were in a PHP script.